# Trying to convert string values to array in pandas dataframe

Tags: arrays, regex, pandas, object

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
Company   CompanyDetails
A         [{"companyId": 1482, "companyAddress": 'sampleaddress1', "numOfEmployees": 500}]
B         [{"companyId": 1437, "companyAddress": 'sampleaddress2', "numOfEmployees": 50}]
C         [{"companyId": 1452, "companyAddress": 'sampleaddress3', "numOfEmployees": 10000}]
```

When I execute `df.dtypes` I find that both the `Company` and `CompanyDetails` columns are objects.

`df[['CompanyDetails']].iloc[0, :]` would return `'{["companyId": 1482, "companyAddress": 'sampleaddress1', numOfEmployees: 500]}'` (there will be quotes ' ' around my array").

I am trying to extract the details within the dictionary in the `CompanyDetails` column so that I can add new columns to my dataframe to look like this:

```
Company   CompanyId   CompanyAddress   numOfEmployees   
A          1482      'sampleaddress1'         500
B          1437      'sampleaddress2'         50
C          1452      'sampleaddress3'       10000
```

I tried something like this as I was trying to convert the CompanyDetails column to contain arrays  for all my values so I can easily extract each property in the object.

```
import ast
df['CompanyDetails'] = df['CompanyDetails'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

However, the above code caused this error

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: <ast.Name object at 0x000002D73D0C13A0>
```

Would appreciate any help on this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because it's actually not valid JSON. `numOfEmployees` is not quoted, and JSON required ALL keys to be double-quoted.

The easiest, safest (in terms of likelyhood to break) way I can think of to fix this would be to repair the JSON using a regular expression replace:

```
df['CompanyDetails'] = df['CompanyDetails'].str.replace(r',\s*(\w+)\s*:', r', "\1":', regex=True)
```

Then do your other stuff:

```
import ast
df['CompanyDetails'] = df['CompanyDetails'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df = pd.concat([df.drop('CompanyDetails', axis=1), pd.json_normalize(df['CompanyDetails'].explode())], axis=1)
```

...or whatever you have in mind.

Comment: Hi @richardec, thanks a lot for your help. I tried your solution but unfortunately am still getting the same malformed node or string error. *Sorry I also just realized I missed out the double quotes("") around numOfEmployees when I posted the question, but I actually have double quotes around all the properties in my object when testing out so the error isn't caused by the double quotes.

Comment: Okay @Kalamazoo. Sorry about that - I should've asked about that first :). Will you please provide a sample of your dataframe via `print(df.head().to_dict())`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
import pandas as pd

# Test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Company':['A'], 'CompanyDetails':[[{"companyId": 1482, "companyAddress": 'sampleaddress1', "numOfEmployees": 500}]]})

df['CompanyDetails'] = df['CompanyDetails'].str[0]
df = pd.concat([df.drop(['CompanyDetails'], axis=1), df['CompanyDetails'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
# => >>> df
#      Company  companyId  companyAddress  numOfEmployees
#    0       A       1482  sampleaddress1             500
```

Note:

- `df['CompanyDetails'] = df['CompanyDetails'].str[0]` gets the first item from each list since each of them only contains one item
- `pd.concat([df.drop(['CompanyDetails'], axis=1), df['CompanyDetails'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)` does the actual expansion and merging with the current dataframe.